# model difference middle tier xpand

Tags: c#, devexpress, xaf

I am trying to get the Demo provided in expand framework source to work located in 
"Xpand-Source-17.1.3.6\Demos\Middle Tier\E4035-Remoting" to work out of the box but i get the exception below.Specifically i want to use the model difference in a remoting scenario.

Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Server stack trace: 
   at DevExpress.ExpressApp.Security.SecurityStrategy.GetObjectSpaces()
   at DevExpress.ExpressApp.Security.SecurityStrategy.RegisterProcessors(Dictionary`2 processors, Object permissionsProvider, IObjectSpace objectSpace)
   at DevExpress.ExpressApp.Security.SecurityStrategy.CreateSelectDataSecurityCore(IObjectSpace objectSpace)
   at DevExpress.ExpressApp.Security.SecurityStrategy.CreateSelectDataSecurity(IObjectSpace objectSpace)
   at DevExpress.ExpressApp.Security.ClientServer.SecuredSerializableObjectLayer.CreateSerializableObjectLayerCore(IClientInfo clientInfo, IDataLayer dataLayer, IRequestSecurityStrategyProvider securityStrategyProvider, UnitOfWork& result_parentSession, ISecurityRule& securityRule, Boolean allowICommandChannelDoWithSecurityContext)
   at DevExpress.ExpressApp.Security.ClientServer.SecuredSerializableObjectLayer.GetSerializableObjectLayer(IClientInfo clientInfo, UnitOfWork& result_parentSession)
   at DevExpress.ExpressApp.Security.ClientServer.SecuredSerializableObjectLayerBase.DevExpress.ExpressApp.Security.ClientServer.ISecuredSerializableObjectLayer.LoadObjects(IClientInfo clientInfo, XPDictionaryStub dictionary, ObjectStubsQuery[] queries)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr md, Object[] args, Object server, Object[]& outArgs)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.SyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at DevExpress.ExpressApp.Security.ClientServer.ISecuredSerializableObjectLayer.LoadObjects(IClientInfo clientInfo, XPDictionaryStub dictionary, ObjectStubsQuery[] queries)
   at DevExpress.Xpo.SerializableObjectLayerClient.LoadObjects(Session session, ObjectsQuery[] queries)
   at DevExpress.Xpo.Logger.LogManager.Log[T](String category, LogHandler`1 handler, MessageHandler`1 createMessageHandler)
   at DevExpress.Xpo.Session.GetObjects(ObjectsQuery query)
   at DevExpress.Xpo.Session.GetObjects(XPClassInfo classInfo, CriteriaOperator criteria, SortingCollection sorting, Int32 topSelectedRecords, Boolean selectDeleted, Boolean force)
   at DevExpress.Xpo.Helpers.XPObjectTypesManager.GetAllTypes()
   at DevExpress.Xpo.Session.<>c__DisplayClass3a.b__38()
   at DevExpress.Xpo.Logger.LogManager.Log[T](String category, LogHandler`1 handler, MessageHandler`1 createMessageHandler)
   at DevExpress.Xpo.Session.GetObjectByKey(Type classType, Object id)
   at DevExpress.ExpressApp.Xpo.XPObjectSpace.GetObjectByKey(Type objectType, Object key)
   at DevExpress.ExpressApp.Security.ClientServer.ServerSecurityClient.get_User()
   at Xpand.ExpressApp.ModelDifference.DataStore.Queries.QueryUserModelDifferenceObject.get_UsersContainsOperator()
   at Xpand.ExpressApp.ModelDifference.DataStore.Queries.QueryUserModelDifferenceObject.GetActiveModelDifferences(String applicationName, String name, DeviceCategory deviceCategory)
   at Xpand.ExpressApp.ModelDifference.DictionaryStores.XpoUserModelDictionaryDifferenceStore.GetActiveDifferenceObjects(DeviceCategory deviceCategory)
   at Xpand.ExpressApp.ModelDifference.DictionaryStores.XpoUserModelDictionaryDifferenceStore.LoadCore(ModelApplicationBase userDiff)
   at DevExpress.ExpressApp.ApplicationModelManager.CreateLayerByStore(String id, ModelStoreBase store)
   at DevExpress.ExpressApp.XafApplication.LoadUserDifferences()
   at DevExpress.ExpressApp.XafApplication.Logon(PopupWindowShowActionExecuteEventArgs logonWindowArgs)
   at DevExpress.ExpressApp.Win.WinApplication.Logon(PopupWindowShowActionExecuteEventArgs logonWindowArgs)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: the demo source is not modified.other modules work fine but the model difference module under remoting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remoting is rather old technology as such the E4035 demo is not updated nor tested often. Instead you may use the E4036-WCF demo which is [EasyTested](https://documentation.devexpress.com/eXpressAppFramework/113211/Functional-Testing/EasyTest-Basics) on each build.